# Understanding jQuery Selector using foreach

Tags: jquery, foreach, jquery-selectors

I am having trouble understanding why my selector is not working for a foreach loop.

My DOM looks as such:

```
<div id="page1" class="ui-droppable">

    <div class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging signatureInstance selected btn-delete" style="position: absolute; left: 185px; top: 470px;">
        <img src="http://example.com/img/field.png">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove btn-delete"><span></span></span>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging signatureInstance selected btn-delete" style="position: absolute; left: 171px; top: 562px;">
        <img src="http://example.com/img/field.png">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove btn-delete"><span></span></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Would someone kindly explain why the following selector is not valid for a foreach iteration?

```
$('#page1 .signatureInstance').forEach(function(index) {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

or

```
$('#page1 .ui-draggable .ui-draggable-handle .ui-draggable-dragging signatureInstance .selected .btn-delete').forEach(function(index) {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

or even:

```
$('#page1 div').forEach(function(index) {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** for iterate over jQuery object, it's built for it.

> The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element. ( Taken from https://api.jquery.com/each/ )

**[`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** using for iterate an array not for jQuery object colection.

```
$('#page1 .signatureInstance').each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

For a better understanding  **[Iterating over jQuery and non-jQuery Objects](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/)**

Comment: Well I feel silly. Thank you. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @Nathan_Sharktek : glad to help